# Benefits of using Zend Framework over CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, zend-framework

*Note: This is not another "What's the difference" or "What's better" question.*

I have been using CodeIgniter for a couple of years now, I find it very good in every aspect - great community(support), lots of information and libraries, hacks, etc., it is easy to learn AND it's easy to code and to read it's code.

For a couple of months now I have been using Zend Framework. I am getting used to it now and mostly I'm coding everything using it right now because of the job requirements. I see the difference between the two, but I can't see any benefits on using ZF besides the huge amount of libraries. (CI has sparks, which makes ZF have better library selection only in rare situations where you need some uncommon functionality).

Now my question is what are the benefits of using Zend Framework over CodeIgniter? (Both ZF, the first and the second).

Please don't tell me the difference between the two, there are many questions about that here, I want to know why most of the people that say they outgrown CI go to ZF and worship it, as my personal opinion is that ZF is a framework with a different approach(not better or worse, different) that makes it harder and longer to code almost anything. I would like to see some constructive list of arguments.

P.S. Some say ZF is better because it uses patterns and stuff and that singletons should be used rarely and only under some certain circumstances which is not the case with CodeIgniter - I could never understand this as I see only benefits in using a singleton for proper MVC.

Comment: *Note: This is not another ... "What's better" question.* But it's still a subjective question, no?

Comment: Yes it is subjective, but does that make it a bad question? It's constructive and has a point. Should someone explain why this question is bad?

Comment: I won't understand why some SE users first they start downvoting rather than thinking to give answer to question.Its a relevant question So +1 from my end.

Comment: That's why I added a note in the beginning, because some of them don't even read the question properly.

Comment: First bullet point of http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask -- every answer is equally valid. "I have outgrown CI because of X", "I left CI because Zend has Y", "I prefer Zend because it does Z better than CI".

Comment: @ta.speot.is these are the answers I expect to see, they can show the good sides of the framework that I'm likely overseeing for now.

Answer (score 3):

I have limited experience with CI but it does seem to be more of a black box type framework then Zend Framework, which may be more limiting to the developer in certain situations.

But the most obvious advantage to me, is Zend Technologies and the reputation of Andi Gutmans and Zeev Surask.

For better or worse it seems that many enterprises have decided that Zend Framework is the way to go. Not sure if this will hold true for ZF2, time will tell.

Developers are far more flexible then the companies they work for.

Comment: About black box, I must say I see your point here, it requires a bit deeper understanding of the framework as a whole than ZF. I can't say reputation is something important but it's an argument. And about enterprises - that's what I ask, why do they decide to go with ZF and not CI, in this case, I remember how fast things were implemented and tested in CI and how long it takes in ZF (that's my experience).

Comment: I gotta wonder if the difference might just be the licensing, it seems the CI just recently went through a rather large license change.

Comment: There was no commercial license and were no for at least two years

Comment: That was likely a large problem for at least some companies. The new CI license looks more enterprise friendly, where ZF made a point of having an enterprise friendly license from the beginning. Remember 2 years for a company is nothing, give them at least 10 years to figure out something changed.